# Laravel9 How to combine this two controller DateFilter/JoinTable without messing the Reservation ID?

Tags: laravel

1. Date Filter

   ```
   $todayDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
   $reservations = Reservation::when(
       $request->date != null,
       function ($query) use ($request) {
           return $query->whereDate('date', $request->date);
       },
       function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
           return $q->whereDate('date', $todayDate);
       }
   )
       ->paginate(10);

   return view('users.reservations.manage', compact('reservations'));
   ```
2. Join Tables

   ```
   $reservations = Reservation::join('patients', 'patients.id', '=', 'reservations.patient_id')
       ->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'reservations.service_id')
       ->get();

   return view('users.reservations.manage', compact('reservations'));
   ```

trying to fix the reservation ID according to its data while having filter date and join table.

Comment: You need to provide more info on what you are trying to achieve and explain more on what is the issue and what output you are trying to get. So examples would be good.

Comment: Super quick tip, `\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')` that can be reduce even more, making it more readabale to `now()->toDateString()` (literally [`now`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-now), not `Carbon::now()`)

Comment: any tips about time like this? thanks btw <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer now thanks all!

```
$todayDate =  now()->toDateString();
$reservations = Reservation::selectRaw('patients.*,services.*, reservations.id as id, reservations.*')
        ->join('patients', 'patients.id', '=', 'reservations.patient_id')
        ->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'reservations.service_id')
        ->when($request->date, function ($query, $date) {
            return $query->whereDate('reservations.date', $date);
        }, function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
            return $query->whereDate('reservations.date', $todayDate);
        })
        ->paginate(10);
```